# 'SqlConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the code:

```
public void SqlDbConnect()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, user, password);
    conn.Open();
}
```

I try to make connection via server name, user and pass.

Comment: You can't just make up method and constructor signatures.  Refer to your intellisense and the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to format the string and then pass that string to the constructor (This is a C# 6 specific feature):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection($"Data Source={server};User ID={user};Password={password};");
```

Or in older C# versions you can use `string.Format`:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, user, password));
```

Comment: you should mentioned that the earlier one is a C#6 syntax which may not work in older version of VS

Comment: @Rahul is saying that specify that it's a **C# 6** feature.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `string.Format()` part of your code:

```
public void SqlDbConnect()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, user, password));
    conn.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to pass a formatted string to the constructor, do it like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, user, password));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case the placeholder string and three values are consider as parameters to the constructor of the `SqlConnection` class, that cause the error, since *'SqlConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments'*. No worries you are almost there you have to use like the following:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", server, user, password));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Number of [Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are 3.

1. empty
2. string
3. (string, SqlCredential)